# need to create class variable which is subclass of that class, how to manage the reference

Tags: python, design-patterns

Please consider the following code as example of the problem.

```
class State:
    START: State = StartState()    # Problem Here - StartState
    END: State = EndState()        # Problem Here - EndState

    @classmethod
    def get_current(cls, context: Context) -> "State":
        if context.just_beginning :
            return cls.START
        return cls.END

class StartState(State):
    ...

class EndState(State):
    ...
```

The code can't run since StartState and EndStart is not define.

However, I can't move **StartState** and **EndState** on top of State since State is not define instead.

Please guide me to do this in Python.

Comment: Can you please provide some explanation as to what you are trying to achive?

Comment: I try to do State Pattern which separate state control from the main object (context class), following from the book "Refactoring to Pattern" 
All state is separated to each subclass which derive from one base class with this context class will have zero knowledge on which state it now just hold one instance of  state then any logic related state will handle on state subclass.

Comment: Note that: The book also reduce the code by let BaseState class hold each instance of State subclass with this each context will not need to instantiate new State instance just take the reference of the current one.

Answer (score 2):

There's no good reason for `StartState` and `EndState` to be defined as classes when they are meant to represent only a single state each. Make them "constant" (spelled in all uppercase by convention) instances of `State` instead.

The `get_current` method should also be more suitably defined as an instance method of the `Context` class since what you want is really to find the state given the current context:

```
class State:
    pass

class Context:
    def get_state(self) -> State:
        if self.just_beginning:
            return START_STATE
        return END_STATE

START_STATE = State()
END_STATE = State()
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit of explanation of your question might have helped. But here's a code snippet that can help you:

```
class State:
    START: "State"
    END: "State"

    @classmethod
    def get_current(cls, context: "Context") -> "State":
        if context.just_beginning:
            return cls.START
        return cls.END

class StartState(State):
    ...

class EndState(State):
    ...

State.START = StartState()
State.END = EndState()
```

You can first declare the State.START and State.END types first inside the class.. and then once your class ends you can initialize the values by calling the StartState() and EndState() functions